# Spec for per page information in PDF (XMP)

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, specifications, xmp

I create one PDF from N images. That's easy and straightforward with this command line:

```
convert front1.png back1.png front2.png back2.png result.pdf
```

Unfortunately some information gets lost in this process. The file `result.pdf` has four pages, but it is not clear if it contains two pages with front and back, or if it contains for front pages.

I would like to store this information in the meta data of the created `result.pdf`.

Is there an official standard to store the front/back information in PDF?

I tried to find something here, but could not find relevant information: http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/standards.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the pdf specification (1.7) at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

On page 580 (under interactive features) it lists that you can set preferences such as duplex and simplex.

I don't know whether this is possible using ImageMagick.
I know it is possible using iText.

See this question : [Printing a PDF duplex using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827760/printing-a-pdf-duplex-using-java)

Comment: Yes, there something under the heading "Duplex". There can be Simplex, DuplexFlipShortEdge, DuplexFlipLongEdge. AFAIK these values are for the whole document. I guess I would need something like "this particular page is a front-side (or back-side)".

Answer (score 3):

As far as the PDF format is concerned, pages are pages: they aren't
 truly considered to be 'front' or 'back'

That concept only becomes meaningful when the pages are rasterized onto a physical piece of paper, i.e. printed.

That doesn't mean PDF is completely ignorant of the concept.

There are a couple of ways it comes into play:

- PDF can carry an internal indicator of whether the document is intended to be printed in Duplex (there are a few options for this,
  as mentioned in Joris's answer). However, these are really just
  advisements to the print system you send it through. There is no
  guarantee that a given print system will actually respect the
  setting and put pages on both sides of the paper in the way you expect.
- The *content* of the PDF may be *laid out* as if it were to be printed duplex (e.g. mirrored page layouts, etc.). But this is just part of the content stream; the PDF format itself is agnostic (other than the options mentioned above).

So it's difficult to say a given page is 'front' or 'back'. You could check if the Duplex flag is set, and if it is, take the page number and divide by two: it's a front page if it's even and a back page if it's odd (remember that page numbers start with zero in PDF).

But there can still be edge cases.

For example, if you were to print a range (say pages 3-7), and you expect page 3 to be a 'back' page, the first page out of the printer likely won't be blank on it's front and have page 3 on the back (which is what you'd expect from what I suggested above).

Most printers will start on the front of the first sheet of paper, and your 'front' and 'back' pages will be out of order.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use articles: section 8.3.2 in the PDF reference v1.7. You could have 2 articles, one for the front pages, and another for the back pages.

PDF Reference v1.7 - 8.3.2: "Some types of documents may contain sequences of content items that are logically connected but not physically sequential".